# Vim - transformation of structured text with macros or even another vim feature

Tags: vim, data-structures, macros

I am reading/learning a bit about vim, and found that macros can be used for repeating actions. My question is: is possible with vim to achieve following text transformation using macros (or some other vim magic)

**Input:**

```
- 1 Show invisibles (2:52)
- 2 Tabs and Spaces (6:22)
- 3 Whitespace preferences and filetypes (3:29)
- 4 Tidying whitespace (4:33)
January 2010


- 5 Indentation commands (5:41)
- 6 Working with buffers (3:28)
- 7 Working with windows (5:32)
- 8 Working with tabs (3:17)
February 2010
```

**Output:**

```
January 2010
- 1 Show invisibles (2:52)
- 2 Tabs and Spaces (6:22)
- 3 Whitespace preferences and filetypes (3:29)
- 4 Tidying whitespace (4:33)


February 2010
- 5 Indentation commands (5:41)
- 6 Working with buffers (3:28)
- 7 Working with windows (5:32)
- 8 Working with tabs (3:17)
```

There are steps that I would take, but do not know how to write this in vim:

1. If the line is starting with dash, remember it's line number and move to next line
2. If the line starting with dash is found again, move cursor until non dash starting line is found
3. If the line is found which is not starting with dash remember it's position and delete this line (dd)
4. Skip one line above the line number that was remembered in step 1 and Append (p) the deleted line
5. Increment the counter which holds non dash line by 2 (there are two spaces between records)
6. Jump with cursor to this incremented line and start with step 1.

Here is another, more elegant (i think) approach but it requires reading file from backwards:

1. If the line is found which is not starting with dash delete this line (dd)
2. If the line which is starting with dash is found move to next line
3. If empty line is found append the deleted line (p)
4. Move cursor until the non dash line is found again and start with step 1.

Is this possible in VIM? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

try this cmd:

```
:g/^[^-]/norm! dd(P
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you very much. Can you please explain what does `(` symbol means? I think `g/^[^-]/` construction stands for something like: make this action on any line that do not begins with dash? Also the `norm!` is something like enter i guess (in respect to Ingo Karkat reply)?

Comment: `:h (` , `:h normal` and `:h :g` you will find the answer. @WakanTanka ;)

Comment: vim golf: `g/^[^-]/m'(-`

Answer (score 1):

Here is Kent's solution as a macro (`<CR>` means pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
qq/^[^-]<CR>dd(Pq
```

This records into register `q`. You repeat via `@q`.

If you clear the register with `qqq` beforehand, and end the macro with `@qq@q` instead of `q`, you'll have a *recursive macro* that repeats itself until there's no more work to do. (Here, you'll need to `:set nowrapscan`, or it'll loop forever.)

Comment: Thank you. If I am understanding correctly you normally end macro with name of register which you start record in? What does @qq@q do ? I am assuming that '@q' means that the macro is called again (recursion) 'q' means regular quit, and '@q' simply call this macro. Am I right?

Comment: A macro is always ended with `q`; and you're right about how the recursion works.